# Does OEAP padding limit the size of my modulous to the size fo the hash function?

Tags: hash, rsa, public-key, padding

im looking  at wiki at the moment as how to use oeap padding and it appears, help  me out if im wrong as G(r) - expands r to the size of the padded message, I am then limited by the size of my hash function as say a SHA-256 hash function would expand to only 256 bits, but what if I had a 2048 bit modulus? I'm unsure if there are any 2000+bit hash functions out there, or could I use a series  of different r values, hash them and use the concatenation of the hash outputs to create a 2000  bit xor?

Comment: Effectively same question as http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14995/selection-of-cryptographic-functions-for-oaep although the better answer there http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/22645/12642 is lower-voted. In short G and H aren't *just* a hash, but a slightly more complicated iterated hash called Mask Generation Function defined in PKCS1/rfc2437/rfc3447.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, would you mind giving a complete answer here?

Comment: Wow, I just looked at the [Wikipedia description of OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) and it is completely and utterly wrong. I mean, it doesn't even have MGF1 in there... Oh, that's indeed also in the other Q/A... Hmm.